# How to fix the regexp to match my string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string `key1=[subKey1=[val1,val2=[k1,k2]],val3,val4,subKey2=[aaa,bbb]],key2=val5,key3,key4=[1,2,3]` i have to parse this string and process found data in a loop.

I've wrote this regexp: `(([^=]+)=(\[(\S+)\],?|[a-z0-9-_]+))|([a-z0-9-_]+)` but it cannot capture `key1` part because `key4` expression ends with `]` character, how do i fix my regexp to match the string?\

```
regex=re.compile('(([^=]+)=(\[(\S+)\],?|[a-z0-9-_]+))|([a-z0-9-_]+)')
string="key1=[subKey1=[val1,val2=[k1,k2]],val3,val4,subKey2=[aaa,bbb]],key2=val5,key3,key4=[1,2,3]"

for i in regex.findall(string):
   #Do Stuff
```

Comment: @pasabaporaqui im doing it on python

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @AruneshSingh get all matched data and use it in a loop, like first it should find all `key1` data then `key2`'s and till the end

Comment: @pasabaporaqui it alsmot worked... regexp still cannot match a string like `key1` if it's in the end. it can find it but not the full pattern

Comment: @PYPL please update it in question for clarity. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regexp is unfit to parse anything that has a recursive pattern in it. Use a real context-free language parser instead. Otherwise you have to restrain your language to a much simpler format.

Or try to convert this with substitutions to a JSON format and use a JSON parser.

Comment: It's been awhile since i asked this question but today i had to look into this project again... have to admit that regex is not the best solution to work with such config file format so i switched to XML completely.

Answer (score 1):

```
import regex
x="key1=[subKey1=[val1,val2=[k1,k2]],val3,val4,subKey2=[aaa,bbb]],key2=val5,key3,key4=[1,2,3]"
print [i for i,j in regex.findall("([^,=]+=(\[(?:[^\[\]]|(?2))+\])|[^,]*)",x) if i]
```

Use `recursive regex` available in `regex` module.

Output : `['key1=[subKey1=[val1,val2=[k1,k2]],val3,val4,subKey2=[aaa,bbb]]', 'key2=val5', 'key3', 'key4=[1,2,3]']`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly alternative approach that uses Python's [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html?highlight=ast#ast.literal_eval) function:

```
import ast, re

orig_text = """key1=[subKey1=[val1,val2=[k1,k2]],val3,val4,subKey2=[aaa,bbb]],key2=val5,key3,key4=[1,2,3]"""
quoted_values = re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', r'"\1"', orig_text)
assignments_removed = re.sub(r'("[a-zA-Z0-9]+?"\s?=\s*)', '', quoted_values)

print ast.literal_eval(assignments_removed)
```

This would at least give you all the values as follows to work with:

```
([['val1', ['k1', 'k2']], 'val3', 'val4', ['aaa', 'bbb']], 'val5', 'key3', ['1', '2', '3'])
```

This works by first quoting all of the values, and then removing all of the assignments to allow `literal_eval` to work. The structure is preserved.